# Proving Logical Equivalences Involving Predicates & Quantifiers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If we prove LHS = RHS. Would that be considered a valid prove or is there other way to prove it?

Suppose the question is ∀(()∧¬()) ≡ ∀() ∧ ¬∃ Q()

My solution:

∀(()∧¬()) ≡ ∀() ∧ ¬∃ Q()

```
    LHS:
    ∀(()∧¬())

    RHS: 
    ∀() ∧ ¬∃ Q()
    ∀() ∧ ∀ ¬Q()      De Morgan’s law in Quantifier
    ∀(P(x) ∧ ¬Q(x))       Distribute Law for Quantifier

Now, Since RHS = LHS the Statement,
    ∀(()∧¬()) ≡ ∀() ∧ ¬∃ Q() is logically Equivalent
```

Comment: This seems like a valid solution, but you should use MathJax to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RHS of $∀(()∧¬()) ≡ ∀() ∧ ¬∃ Q()$ can be written as $∀x P (x) ∧ ∀x Q(x)$ since $∀x S(x)$ is equivalent to $¬∃ S()$

We can prove $∀x (P (x) ∧Q(x)) ≡ ∀x P (x) ∧ ∀x Q(x)$ that as follows:

Sufficiency: suppose that $∀x (P (x) ∧ Q(x))$ is true. Then, for arbitrary $a$, $P (a) ∧ Q(a)$ is true; then $P (a) =
Q(a) = t r ue$ (for arbitrary $a$). Therefore, $∀x P (x) ∧ ∀x Q(x)$.

Necessity: suppose that $∀x P (x) ∧ ∀x Q(x)$ is true. Then, $∀x P (x) = ∀x Q(x) = true$. Then, for $x = a$, $P (a) = Q(a) = true$, which means $P (a) ∧Q(a) = t r ue$. We can do that for any a. Therefore, $∀x (P (x) ∧Q(x))$ is true.